# Is $a^{p-1} - 3p - 1$ always composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is propably very easy problem, but I can't crack it. If $p$ is a prime number and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \nmid a$, then $a^{p-1} - 3p - 1$ is a composite number. Is it always true? If it is, how can I prove it? I'm sure I must use Fermat's theorem.

Comment: Hint: show it is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Specifically [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try $p=2, a=9$ then you get $$9^{2-1}-3 \times 2-1=9-6-1=2$$ which is prime.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's why I couldn't prove it's true, thanks!

Comment: You can prove it is divisible by $p$, but then you need to consider whether it might be $p$ itself.  (It might also be negative or zero)

Comment: Another example is $p=5,a=2.$ Then $2^4-3\cdot 5 -1=0$ and $0$ is considered neither composite nor prime. The examples when $(a,p)=(5,2),(9,2),$ and $(2,5)$ are the only counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1}-3p-1$ is divisible by $p.$ So the only way for it to be not composite is if $a^{p-1}-3p-1=\pm p\text{ or }0.$ ($0$ is not considered composite in most definitions.)

Now, in general you need to prove the lemma:

> For integer $n>5,$ $2^{n-1}> 4n+1.$

You can prove this by induction starting with $n=6.$

This means that if $p>5$ and $|a|>1$ that $a^{p-1}-3p-1>p.$

If $p$ is any odd prime and $a=\pm 1$ then $a^{p-1}-3p-1=-3p$ is not prime.

If $p=3$ then $a^2-10=\pm 3\text{ or }0$ has no solution $a.$

If $p=5,$ then $a^4-16=\pm 5\text{ or }0$ has one solution $a=2.$

If $p=2$ then $a^1-7=\pm 2,\text{0}$ has solutions $a=5,7,9.$

Thus this is true except when $(a,p)=(5,2),(7,2),(9,2)$ or $(2,5).$